# How can I trigger the EntityTypeEvents::UPDATE event?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I tried to trigger event on each entity update. This is my **src/EventSubscriber/MySub.php**

```
    use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeEvents;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

    class MySub implements EventSubscriberInterface{

      public function onEntityTypeUpdate(EntityTypeEvents $event)  {
            drupal_set_message("returned from onEntityTypeUpdate"); 
       }

      public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

          $events[EntityTypeEvents::UPDATE][] = array('onEntityTypeUpdate');


    return $events;
  }
}
```

This is my **services.yml** file

```
services:
  custom_sub:
    class: '\Drupal\custom_sub\EventSubscriber\MySub'
    arguments: ['@entity.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

But the message is not displaying after updating the content or content type. Please guide.

Comment: You define arguments but don't use them in your class. Try to delete `arguments: ['@entity.manager']` and clear the cache.

Comment: i did. I could get event triggered while defining a new custom event and using hook_node_insert but not in `EntityTypeEvents::UPDATE`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Both are different events. The hook is triggered when a node is inserted. The event is triggered when the entity type definition is updated, which normally only happens when you install a module which alters the entity type definition of the node entity.

Comment: which means adding field to existing content type would trigger the UPDATE event?

Comment: Not necessarily, only if you add a field storage to the entity type at the same time it would change the database schema of the entity type, but I'm not sure it triggers on changes in the configured fields.